# combine two queries into one one query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

I have two queries which both work but need to combine them into one working query

Query 1

```
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var twoWeeksAgo = now.AddDays(-14);

  var advert =
      from m in db.tbl_Property
      where m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo && m.Prop_Update <= now
      select m;
```

Query 2

```
  var Props = 
      from n in db.tbl_Property.
      Where(c => c.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0)
      select n;
```

Any help or advice welcome

Comment: Does it mean that you want both result sets in single query or that you want to have applied both conditions in single query?

Comment: to have applied both conditions in a single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var twoWeeksAgo = now.AddDays(-14);

var advert = db.tbl_Property
               .Where(m => m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo && m.Prop_Update <= now
                           && m.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0);
```

Or perhaps combining with || instead:

```
var advert = db.tbl_Property
               .Where(m => (m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo && m.Prop_Update <= now)
                           || m.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0);
```

(Note that I haven't used a query expression here as you're *only* using a single where clause.)

Answer (score 3):

I would change those queries to **pass in** the original `IQueryable<Property>` (or whatever the type is), then you can do:

```
var advert = from m in source
             where m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo && m.Prop_Update <= now
             select m;
```

passing `db.tbl_Property` in as the `source`, then:

```
var Props = from n in filteredProperties
            where n.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0
            select n;
```

i.e. composition

Comment: Why 2 LINQ queries when that can be performed in single. and more over he already has 2 query which he want them to be merged into 1

Comment: @Nikhil my assumption here is that there are two discreet filters (applied separately) that need to be combined (composed) **at runtime**, in which case the above is fine. If the idea is to flatten that *at compile time*, then sure, just rewrite the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var advert =
            from m in db.tbl_Property
            where 
                (m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo && m.Prop_Update <= now)
                || (m.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0)

            select m;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var advert = db.tbl_Property.Where(m => m.Prop_Update >= twoWeeksAgo 
     && m.Prop_Update <= now && m.Prop_AvailableSpaces > 0);
```